# "Been around the world twice, talked to everyone once" - "push" meaning

Tags: dialogue, lone-survivor

What is the meaning of "push" in the context of his speech

because I'm seeing that on the french subtitle it mean "baise" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Essentially, the translation is correct.

Spoiled for profanity...

> Baise = Fuck

In this context a "Peter" is a slang name for *Penis*.

The line suggest that the sayer is the best "lover" (pushing peter...I'll leave it to you to figure out where) and has the biggest "peter" than any other person with the same equipment.

This is the Frogman Ballard...and there are a couple of different versions.

**NSFW**

> Been around the world twice, talked to everybody once.
> Seen two whales fuck,
>
> Been to 3 world fairs,
> and I even know a man in Thailand with a wooden Cock.
>
> I push more peter, more sweeter and more completer
>
> Than any other peter pusher around.
>
> I’m a hard bodied hairy chested
>
> Roottin’, toottin’, shootin’, parachutin’ demolition double cap crimpin’ Frogman.
>
> There ain’t nothing I can’t do.
>
> No sky too high, no sea too rough, no muff too tough.
>
> Learned a lot of lessons in my life.
>
> Never shoot a large caliber man with a small caliber bullet.
>
> I drive all kinds of trucks, 2x, 4x, 6x and those big motherfuckers that bend and go "CHHH CHHH” when you step on the brakes.
>
> Anything in life worth doing is worth overdoing, moderation is for cowards.
>
> I’m a lover, I’m a fighter, I’m a UDT Navy SEAL diver.
>
> I’ll wine dine, intertwine.
>
> Then sneak out the back when the re-fueling is done.
>
> So if you’re feeling froggy then you better jump. because this frogman's been there, done that and is going back for more.

More verses at [**Quora**](https://www.quora.com/In-the-movie-Lone-Survivor-what-is-the-meaning-of-Shane-Pattons-character-dialogue)